# Output the contents of an array of lists to a text file?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, file-io, text-files

I currently have an Array of lists as seen here:

```
List<string>[] phase2 = new List<string>[200];
```

Some of the lists inside are initialized with strings(8 each) as seen here:

```
phase2[0] = new List<string>() { "Bob", "Complex", "B", "AOT", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", };
phase2[1] = new List<string>() { "Joe", "Complex", "B", "AOT", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes" };
phase2[2] = new List<string>() { "Bill", "Complex", "A", "AOT", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes" };
```

I am trying to write the contents of each list to a .txt file and have run into a block of my knowledge... I would like each "list" on 1 line. I know how to write an array to a file and a list to a file but not both at the same time. I would love some help figuring this one out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use a "nested" foreach loop, but it is unclear if you want them to write to two separate files, or if you want them to write to the same file. I'll do the second one:

```
foreach (List<string> currentList in phase2)
{
     foreach (string currentElement in currentList)
     {
          //change this out to whatever file output technique you use.               
          Console.Write currentElement + ",";
     }
   //starts a new line
   Console.Write "\n"
}
```

This should give you an idea of where to go (assuming you meant you want to write the contents of each list in a columns/rows style). I almost insist on using a delimiter unless you have a special reason not to. You can use any character, but sticking with standards (, ;  | [tab] ) to separate your columns is really just ensuring compatibility with future applications.

If you don't want a delimiter, then just remove the + "," part.

Replace the Console.Write commands with your File output stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Please see 'ConcatToString' function below :

```
void Main()
{
    List<string>[] phase2 = new List<string>[200];

    phase2[0] = new List<string>() { "Bob", "Complex", "B", "AOT", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", };
    phase2[1] = new List<string>() { "Joe", "Complex", "B", "AOT", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes" };
    phase2[2] = new List<string>() { "Bill", "Complex", "A", "AOT", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes" };

    File.WriteAllText(@"d:\scratch\arrOfWords.txt", ConcatToString(phase2));
}

public string ConcatToString(List<string>[] arrOfWords) 
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(List<string> words in arrOfWords)
    {
        if(words?.Count > 0 ) sb.AppendLine(String.Join(",", words));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @slightly-drifting has pointed out, when traversing 2D data structures you'll need to use nested loops. It could be either a `foreach`, a traditional `for` or even a `while`, depending on your needs.

However, if you aren't concerned about memory allocation or performance (which seems to be the case when dealing with only 200 lines), you may be able to achive it using [File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file) and [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/). Notice that LINQ provides a more user friendly API, but for this problem, under the hood, it still uses the nested loops.

Enough words. Here is a sample:

```
private static void WriteToFile(string filePath, List<string>[] content)
{
    using (var fileWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath))
    {
        foreach (var line in content)
        {
            if (line == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < line.Count; i++)
            {
                fileWriter.Write(line[i]);

                if (i != line.Count - 1)
                {
                    fileWriter.Write(',');
                }
            }

            fileWriter.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}

private static void WriteToFileOneLiner(string filePath, List<string>[] content)
{
    File.WriteAllLines(filePath, content.Where(line => line != null).Select(line => string.Join(',', line)));
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string>[] phase2 = new List<string>[200];
    phase2[0] = new List<string>() { "Bob", "Complex", "B", "AOT", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", };
    phase2[1] = new List<string>() { "Joe", "Complex", "B", "AOT", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes" };
    phase2[2] = new List<string>() { "Bill", "Complex", "A", "AOT", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes" };

    WriteToFile(@"C:\Path\to\my\file.txt", phase2);
    WriteToFileOneLiner(@"C:\Path\to\my\file_oneliner.txt", phase2);
}
```